# dbSimple placeholder-ы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть функция

```
function postDb ($adStore, $dbc) {
    $column=implode(' , ',array_keys($adStore));
    $value=implode("' , '",array_values($adStore));
    $dbc->query("INSERT INTO adStore ($column) VALUE ('$value')");
}
```

Хочу заменить `$column`, `$value` на placeholder-ы.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function postDb ($adStore, $dbc) {
    $dbc->query("INSERT INTO adStore SET ?a", $adStore);
}
```

http://dklab.ru/lib/DbSimple/manual.html#list11